# gitignore all folders under any folder

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I have this structure:

```
versions
├── library-3.1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── options
│   └── armhf
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── rootfs.tar.xz
├── library-3.6
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── options
│   └── x86_64
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── rootfs.tar.xz
...
```

I want git to ignore any folder under `versions/**/` (like `versions/**/armhf` and `versions/**/x86_64`), but keep tracking the files `options` and `Dockerfile`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Ignore everything under 'versions/'...
versions/*

# ...except 'options' and 'Dockerfile'
!versions/**/options
!versions/**/Dockerfile
```

Add any additional files you need to the excluded list.

Alternatively, add a *.gitignore* file to each subdirectory that you want to ignore files in. This may provide better flexibility as the project grows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!versions/**/Dockerfile
!version/**/options
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

Ignore files:

```
 versions/**
```

But not folders:

```
 !versions/**/
```

Then you can exclude some files (because their parent folder are not ignored)

```
 !versions/**/Dockerfile
 !versions/**/option
```

Remember: