# How to use .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, github, path, gitignore

I want to exclude `node_modules` directory except for one file.

This is what the relevant part of my `.gitignore` looks like - I have tried a few things but no luck:

.gitignore

```
....

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

....
```

I think I need to do something like:

```
node_modules/
!node_modules/path/to/index.js
```

But it says [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#git-ignore-patterns) that the above won't work due to some `git` restriction. Anyway, the answer is probably in that link, I'm just having a little trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively ignore all files inside a specific directory except .json files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416391/recursively-ignore-all-files-inside-a-specific-directory-except-json-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20.gitignore%20node_modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way:

```
node_modules/
!node_modules/path/to/index.js
```

Nope! Due to a performance-related quirk in Git, you can not negate a file that is ignored due to a pattern matching a directory.

I don't sure way to

```
git add .
```

to add `your index.js` and all file exclude `node_modules`

But you can use `git add node_modules/path/to/index.js -f`

> -f because your file are ignored by one of your .gitignore files

and use `node_modules/` in `.gitignore`

`git` won't ignore `your index.js` file (added it to cache).

Comment: Yes, if you add `node_modules` to `.gitignore` before `git add your_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to move your react-native-calendars directory outside your node_modules directory, e.g move it to a directory name nmod2. and then when you import it, add the path like `var react-cal = require('./nmod2/react-native-calendars');` instead of `var react-cal = require('react-native-calendars');`. So that you can put the whole node_modules directory in .gitignore. Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what to do, why are the .log files relevant?

Comment: Oops, my bad for not reading your post carefully. I thought you want to exclude those 2 files. I'll update my answer

Comment: oh i see, you think I am trying to remove the `.log` files - that is just what my default .gitignore file is. i am trying to remove a file from `node_modules` folder from being committed.

Comment: so i need to commit my whole `node_modules` folder and then go onto github and remove all of it except one directory path? that seems weird and might take a while

Comment: i need everything in my `node_modules` folder to be excluded except for one file...there should be a way to do this with the patterns in the link

Comment: i could probably just keep the whole package folder ex. `!node_modules/react-native-calendars/` but i need to ignore the rest

Comment: okay I misunderstood your intention twice now, my apologies. But do you already have the whole node_modules and its contents in your github repository?

Comment: no, i guess I could do that but it would take me a while to delete everything around the file i want to leave...and how would that even make it work? im guessing it would change some config somewhere by noticing that i do that?

Comment: try moving your react-native-calendars directory outside your node_modules directory, e.g move it to a directory name nmod2. and then when you import it, add the path like `var react-cal = require('./nmod2/react-native-calendars');` instead of `var react-cal = require('react-native-calendars');`. So that you can put the whole node_modules directory in .gitignore. I just tried moving my express library outside node_modules and it works